# how to compute the sum of minimum value in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i'm trying to build k-medoids algorithm in python. i have difficulties in computing the cost. I'm using 3 cluster. For example i have S (the distance matrix for every point to each cluster).

```
S = array([[3.1398624 , 3.04813418, 4.99560254],
       [3.46696607, 2.94348558, 5.47449423],
       [2.68335282, 4.12807209, 4.43433005],
       [2.64792413, 3.48070146, 4.93280055],
       [1.97348315, 3.46405704, 4.20034798],
       [2.62944855, 3.4593389 , 4.9092722 ]])
```

and the assigned label for each point(using the minimum S to assign label), for example:

```
labels = array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

so i try to compute the cost, which is the sum of the minimum distance for each point.

```
def calculate_cost(S):
    cost = 0
    min_cost_idx = np.argmin(S, axis=1)
    for i in range(len(min_cost_idx)):
        cost += np.sum(S[i])
    return cost
```

but it gives me the sum of all  S , not the sum of the minimum  S for each data point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `i` takes value for each row, but not the required index within that row.
You should change your `for` loop to:

```
for i,val in enumerate(min_cost_idx):
    cost += np.sum(S[i][val])
```

Having said that, you can also get rid of the for loop altogether, and take the sum using the `np.min` function.

```
%timeit (calculate_cost(S))
26.9 µs ± 1.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit sum(np.min(S, axis=1))
4.79 µs ± 90.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```